# Android BatteryManager Class Advice

Tags: android, battery

I am trying to build an app which I've never tried before and seeking your help in deciding how to go about it.

I intend to make an app in which I'm showing a custom battery level to the user. I've seen numerous apps in the market that do the same but I don't know how exactly to achieve it.

For Example I intend to create something like below but with my own custom images:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macropinch.pearl

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geekyouup.android.widgets.battery

I've researched and came to know that BatteryManager class in android.os will be the one to use it.

But my main 2 troubles are:

1. I want to show an image which will keep on changing based on the current level of the battery.
2. How to PIN the app on the phone home screen as a widget so that it sticks on the home screen indicating the current battery level.

The approach that I've in my mind:

1. For first I think I can call the battery current level method at regular intervals say every 5 seconds and then based on the level of the battery I change the image accordingly. Although I think this can't be the best way to do it. Please guide if this approach is right. If not then please suggest what could be a more effective and efficient approach.

Also how should I change the image. Is sprite images the best way or is there any other way to do it easily and effectively?

For second, I've never tried it so you have to guide me how to do this exactly.

If you can share some code that can help me achieve my goal that would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading through tutorials on [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html).